# The remote name could not be resolved: 'bucket-2.miniomyserverhost.com'

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-service-fabric, minio

Faced a data copy issue using Azure Fabric Data - minIO

In Azure Fabric Data, I set up a connection to my minIO server, the test connection goes well, I see all the bucket

BUT when I try to access the contents of the cart I get an error

The operation has timed out"
or "The file operation is failed. A WebException with status NameResolutionFailure was thrown. The remote name could not be resolved: 'bucket-2.miniomyserverhost.com' Activity ID: 0794a825-7ba4-dfec4cfc8846"

Judging by the error, I need to adjust the "path style" URLs

But I can't find an example of how to do it right.

Can you suggest

Registered two parameters in the configuration file

MINIO_DOMAIN=(host)domain
MINIO_SERVER_URL=http://(host)domain

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion. To resolve the issue of "The operation has timed out" or:

> The file operation is failed. A `WebException` with status `NameResolutionFailure` was thrown. The remote name could not be resolved

…while accessing the contents of a bucket in Azure Fabric Data using minIO, you need to set up the "path style" URLs correctly.

You have registered two parameters in the configuration file, `MINIO_DOMAIN` and `MINIO_SERVER_URL`. To use path style URLs, set `MINIO_SERVER_URL` to `http://(host):9000`.

Here is an example:

```
MINIO_DOMAIN=myminioserver.com
MINIO_SERVER_URL=http://myminioserver.com:9000
```

Make sure to replace `myminioserver.com` with the actual hostname or IP address of your minIO server.

Comment: MINIO_DOMAIN=myminioserver.com
MINIO_SERVER_URL=http://myminioserver.com:9001 (API port)

after 
systemctl restart minio 
and 
systemctl status minio

The result will be displayed
Feb 07 08:56:44 minio-test minio[129479]: API: http://myminioserver.com:9001
Feb 07 08:56:44 minio-test minio[129479]: Console: http://myip:9002 http://127.0.0.1:9002

But unfortunately in the Factory all the same error